# C++: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'guiBaseObject *' with an rvalue of type 'void'

Tags: c++, initialization, void, openframeworks, rvalue

I'm using openframeworks. This is based on C++.

I have the following code:

```
guiBaseObject *item = panel.addSlider("motor_speed", 0, 0, 100);
```

And I am unable to understand why I receive the following error.

```
/Users/CREATER/Documents/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/apps/myApps/MapamokStepper/src/MotorControl.cpp:38:20: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'guiBaseObject *' with an rvalue of type 'void'
```

Comment: `addSlider` probably returns `void`, so you cannot return a `guiBaseObject*` from it.

Comment: What's the return type of `addSlider()`?

Comment: I don't see  [`addSlider`](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/) in their documentation, but I assume it returns `void`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to the slider, you can do something like this:

```
ofIntSlider motorSpeed;
panel.add(motorSpeed.setup("motor_speed", 0, 0, 100));
```

Answer (score -1):

C++ is a strong-typed language. You really need to typecast the rvalue into the lvalue.
Here in your case it should be like:

```
guiBaseObject *item = (guiBaseObject *)panel.addSlider("motor_speed", 0, 0, 100);
```

otherwise it will give a compile time error.

Comment: Not exactly best practice.

Comment: You can't cast `void` to anything, because it is nothing.

Comment: It's a (moderately) strongly typed language, so you need to declare variables of the right type, not use casts to force invalid code through the compiler.